# How to remove line of text using JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

Example:

```
var name = "I am wearing a red shirt and I love to play darts. Thank you";
```

my container is about 200px width

then the string would be like:

```
"I am wearing a red shirt 

and I love to play darts.

Thank you"
```

now, I want to remove the text from the last line of my string because I wanted it to be display only 2 lines. If my string reaches the 3rd line, I want it to be deleted.

I have 15px clientHeight. and I only want to allow 30px clientHeight or 2 lines of string only.

I WANT TO MAKE THIS OUTPUT:

```
"I am wearing a red shirt 

and I love to play darts."
```

the third line is automatically deleted

Comment: What have you tried and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: I edited the question. and I write what exactly I wanted to be the output. may string is not in 3 line. it is automatically make 3 lines because if I have long string, and since I have container that is only 300px width, the string will automatically create new line. And I wanted it to have 2 lines only. the following lines of string will be automatically deleted. Only first 2 lines will be displayed

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, though. Please note that SO is neither a tutorial nor code-writing service.

Comment: On what environment? Browser? Node.js? Something else? What container? Which font?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how exactly you want to do it. If you just want to show two lines of text:

```css
#text-container {
    width: 200px
    height: 3em; /* height = max-height = 2 * line-height */
    max-height: 3em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

If you want it to only show two *sentences*, its a bit harder. You will either need to pre-process the text with Javascript beforehand and/or create separate elements for each line of text you want to show.